# Is there a way to modify the SetBinding variable in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, binding

I have a code that should generate a Ranking of the players with the 3 highest scores and show it on the screen. I use Binding to take the elements of the list and generate an item for each player, with their email and score. However, I would like to know if there is any way to display only a part of the email, and not the complete one. For example: example.email@gmail.com, I would like to display only example.email, but I don't know if there is any way to edit the element that will go to the screen through SetBinding. The code that generates the Ranking is below:

```
List<UserRankingDTO> ranking = new UserQuestionHistoryService(StoreVarsHelper.UserToken).GetUsersRanking(3);

            ListView listView = new ListView
            {
                Margin = 8,
                ItemsSource = ranking,
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
                {
                    Label nameLabel = new Label();
                    nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "UserName");
                    nameLabel.TextColor = Color.White;
                    Label scoreLabel = new Label();
                    scoreLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("UserScore", BindingMode.OneWay,
                                        null, null, "Pontuação: {0:d}"));
                    scoreLabel.TextColor = Color.White;

                    return new ViewCell
                    {

                        View = new StackLayout
                        {
                            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#2b2b80"),
                            Children =
                            {
                                new StackLayout
                                {
                                    Spacing = 0,
                                    Children =
                                    {
                                        nameLabel,
                                        scoreLabel,
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                })
            };
```

"Username" is the attribute of the UserRankingDTO class that has the email I would like to modify as stated above.

Comment: either create a read-only property in your model/viewmodel that returns the substring you want to use, or use an `IValueConverter` in your binding to modify the value before it is displayed

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the reply! Could you send me a link to how IValueConverter works, please?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+ivalueconverter